# How to access JsArray of double via index in Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

In Play 2.3 framework, the response is parsed as JSON. Given the following data:

```
{"content": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

I tried to access every other elements of the array (i.e. `1, 3, 5`) by

```
// Scala
val array = (response \ "content").as[JsArray].value
for (i <- 0 until array.size / 2)
  println(array(i * 2))
```

But `array(i*2)` raised error. What would be the canonical approach of access JsArray via index?

Comment: You can parse as `Array[Int]` instead of `JsArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
for(i <- 0 until array.size if i % 2 == 0)
  println(array(i * 2))
```

A better way would be to loop over the elements instead:

```
for((a,i) <- array.zipWithIndex if i % 2 == 0)
  println(a)
```